# Nested macros and hyperlink problem

Tags: macros, hyperref

I am new to LaTeX and write a document with the use of the `hyperref` package. Here is this simple scenario which I do not understand. I have to use a macro like `\ccc` in `\hyperlink` but it causes 6 errors and I can not fix the problem:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\hypertarget{link:two}{targettwo}

\newcommand{\aaa}{link:one}
\newcommand{\ccc}{\renewcommand{\aaa}{link:two} \aaa}
\hyperlink{\ccc}{something} %no link produced, only text: "link:two" and 6 errors
\end{document}
```

---

```
log:
.
.
.
! Use of \hyper@link@ doesn't match its definition.
\@ifnextchar ... \reserved@d =#1\def \reserved@a {
                                                  #2}\def \reserved@b {#3}\f...
l.21 \hyperlink{\ccc}{aaa}
                           %6 errors
If you say, e.g., `\def\a1{...}', then you must always
put `1' after `\a', since control sequence names are
made up of letters only. The macro here has not been
followed by the required stuff, so I'm ignoring it.

! Argument of \@firstoftwo has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.21 \hyperlink{\ccc}{aaa}
                           %6 errors
I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and it will go away.

Runaway argument?
! Paragraph ended before \@firstoftwo was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.21 \hyperlink{\ccc}{aaa}
                           %6 errors
I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.

! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\hyper@link@ ...\Hy@safe@activestrue \edef \x {#3}
                                                  \ifx \Hy@tempa \@empty \to...
l.21 \hyperlink{\ccc}{aaa}
                           %6 errors
I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and
you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.

Runaway argument?
{\let \reserved@d =*\def 
! Paragraph ended before \hyper@link was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.21 \hyperlink{\ccc}{aaa}
                           %6 errors
I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.

! Too many }'s.
\x ...r@link {link}{\let \reserved@d =*\def \par }
                                                  {\Hy@safe@activesfalse aaa}
l.21 \hyperlink{\ccc}{aaa}
                           %6 errors
You've closed more groups than you opened.
Such booboos are generally harmless, so keep going.
.
.
.
```

I am Using TeXnicCenter with MikTeX 2.9.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What's the purpose of this nesting? There may be better ways to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct syntax is `\hyperlink{<name>}{<text>}` where `<name>` must be a valid, expandable label name. It can not contain any non-expandable commands. This excludes any form of assignment, e.g. `\renewcommand`. The name must instead expand directly to some text only.

So your:

```
\newcommand{\aaa}{link:one}
\newcommand{\ccc}{\renewcommand{\aaa}{link:two} \aaa}
\hyperlink{\ccc}{something}
```

is wrong and will never work. You need to write it some way like this:

```
\newcommand{\aaa}{link:one}
\newcommand{\ccc}{\renewcommand{\aaa}{link:two}}
\ccc
\hyperlink{\aaa}{something}
```

This means: Do any redefinition of `\aaa` before `\hyperlink` and make sure that `\aaa` expands to only the name.

If you give a more specific example of your exact use, then we can help you further.

Comment: I can't understand why your example (now) and my work.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: The now gone "example" was the original text posted in the question. I only  accidentally pasted it at the end of my answer. ;-) Note that a simple expandable macro works, because it is expanded internally. Either using `\csname .. \endcsname` or by writing it into an auxiliary file. Both do not support unexpandable stuff.

Comment: Should I remove my answer?

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: If you think so. Using `$ccc` doesn't make much sense IMO.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: Problem is solved I gess, thanks. But in every real case one should be able to get the macro's output in a fully expandable form. Is there any common way to do this?(same question in: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51770/why-hyperlink-rightmark-does-not-work-in-fancyhead-and-inside-some-other-m )