# Hyperlinked sectionnames in fancyheader

Tags: hyperref, header-footer, fancyhdr

I am trying to create a header that consist of chaptername and sectionname (chaptername:sectionname) both of them a hyperlink to chapter and section respectively. I am using Hungarian language so there are many accented word, and - as I gathered - `hyperref` do not support accented links and after all, section names can be the same in different chapters so I need to get some unique names. So I generate a unique ASCII section name (see `\Section`) and in `\sectionmark` I concatenated it with the name of the section and in `\fancyhead` I try to separate them again and using them in a `\hyperlink` command, but so far I failed. Here is the brief (not working) code example:

```
\documentclass[pdftex,a4paper,12pt,oneside]{book}%

\usepackage[latin2]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\hypersetup{colorlinks,                               linkcolor=blue!80,filecolor=Orange,urlcolor=red!60,citecolor=magenta,
              linktoc=all,
            hypertexnames=false,
            unicode=true,
            bookmarksnumbered=false,
        pdfmenubar=true,%
          pdftoolbar=true
         }

\newcommand{\chapterlinkname}{}
\newcommand{\setchapterlinkname}[1]{\renewcommand{\chapterlinkname}{#1}}
\newcommand{\chapterlink}[1]{\setchapterlinkname{lnk:chap#1}\hypertarget{\chapterlinkname}{}}
\newcommand{\Chapter}[2]{\newpage\chapterlink{#2} \chapter{#1}}

\newcommand{\sectionlinkname}{}
\newcommand{\setsectionlinkname}[1]{\renewcommand{\sectionlinkname}{#1}}
\newcommand{\sectionlink}[1]{\setsectionlinkname{\chapterlinkname:sec#1}\hypertarget{\sectionlinkname}{}}
\newcommand{\Section}[2]{\sectionlink{#2}\section{#1}}

\newcommand{\seclink}{}
\newcommand{\secname}{}
\newcommand{\mystrsplit}[4]{
  \renewcommand{#3}{\StrBefore{#1}{#2}}
  \renewcommand{#4}{\StrBehind{#1}{#2}}
}  

%------------------

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} 
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{##1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\sectionlinkname,##1}} 

\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\mystrsplit{\rightmark}{,}{\seclink}{\secname} \hyperlink{\chapterlinkname}{\bfseries\leftmark} : \hyperlink{\seclink}{\bfseries\secname}}  

\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\bfseries\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\addtolength{\headheight}{2.5pt} 
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhead{}\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}} 

\Chapter{Állóképek}{Allokepek}

\Section{Tükörkép}{Tukorkep}

\newpage

\Section{Sírkőgyártó}{Sirkogyarto}

\end{document}
```

I am using MiKTeX 2.9 with TeXnicCenter.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Nested macros and hyperlink problem](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51504/nested-macros-and-hyperlink-problem)

Comment: see at: (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51770/why-hyperlink-rightmark-does-not-work-in-fancyhead-and-inside-some-other-m)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following example first fixes a compatibility problem between hyperref and
magyar. Both redefine `\refstepcounter`. Then `\@currentHref` is available that contains
the name of the anchor used in hyperref's `\refstepcounter`. Then the titles of
the chapters or sections do not need to be used as target or label name.

```
\documentclass[pdftex,a4paper,12pt,oneside]{book}%

\usepackage[latin2]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage[magyar]{babel}
% magyar.ldf redefines \refstepcounter in \extrasmagyar
% and overwrites hyperref's definition.
% The following hacks work around this by
% restoring hyperref's definition that will
% then call magyar.ldf's version.
\begingroup
  \extrasmagyar
  \global\let\MagyarRefstepcounter\refstepcounter
\endgroup
\let\refstepcounter\MagyarRefstepcounter
\usepackage{hyperref}
\let\HyperrefRefstepcounter\refstepcounter
\addto\extrasmagyar{%
  \let\refstepcounter\HyperrefRefstepcounter
}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\hypersetup{colorlinks,
            linkcolor=blue!80,filecolor=Orange,
            urlcolor=red!60,citecolor=magenta,
            linktoc=all,
            hypertexnames=false,
            unicode=true,
            bookmarksnumbered=false,
        pdfmenubar=true,%
          pdftoolbar=true
         }

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} 

% \@currentHref contains the anchor name
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
  \markboth{\protect\hyperlink\@currentHref}{\thechapter. #1}}{}%
}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{%
  \markright{\protect\hyperlink{\@currentHref}{\thesection. #1}}%
}

\fancyhead[LO,RE]{{\bfseries\leftmark} : {\bfseries\rightmark}}  

\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\bfseries\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\addtolength{\headheight}{2.5pt} 
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhead{}\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}} 

\chapter{Állóképek}

\section{Tükörkép}

\newpage

\section{Sírkogyártó}

\end{document}
```