# xstring character comparison and \meaning

Tags: xstring, meaning

```
\documentclass[pdftex,a4paper,12pt,oneside]{book}%

\usepackage{xstring}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\tmpa}{}
\newcommand{\tmpb}{}
\newcommand{\tmpc}{}

\renewcommand{\tmpc}{abcdefg} \noindent tmpc: \tmpc \\
\renewcommand{\tmpa}{\meaning\tmpc} tmpa: \tmpa \\
len: \StrLen{\tmpa} \\
char(20): \StrChar{\tmpa}{20}[\tmpb] \tmpb \\
pos(f): \StrPosition{\tmpa}{f} 

\end{document}
```

Result:

```
tmpc: abcdefg

tmpa: \long macro:->abcdefg

len: 21

char(20): f

pos(f): 0
```

Why? `tmpa` obviously contains character 'f' on the position of 20 as we can find it with `\StrChar`. But that 'f' not the same as the one we are trying to find with `StrPos`. I thought about catcode differences, but did not find anything usable (I might be wrong with changing catcode of 'f' before searching for it).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\meaning\tmpc` produces a string where all characters have category code 12 (but spaces have category code 10). When you compare the strings, the category code 11 `f` is not found.

The working of `\StrPosition` uses delimited argument macros and the delimiter must be the same both for character code and category code.

Indeed, if you say `\StrPosition{\tmpa}{\string f}` the printed result is 20 (`\StrPosition` does complete expansion).

Comment: this "delimited argument macros and the delimiter" slightly obscure to me, but alltoghether, I understand   and well, I am new in latex.:)

Comment: the use of `\string f` is clear but how can I use `\string` before a macro? e.g. `\string\mymacro` results in "\mymacro"

Comment: @pmks Yes, that's what's expected. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I store data using `\markright` (counter value and sectionname) and try to get them back using `\StrBetween{\firstmark}{{\delim}{\delim}` but with package babel `\firstmark` is full of macros and `\StrBetween` can not cope with them. So I use `\StrBetween{\meaning\firstmark}...` and decently get my values. With accented chars and `inputenc` I get coded strings like this in my output:`\IeC {\’\i }\’a\H o\’o\"u\"o`. I thought that it might help to change (’) to (') and I used `\StrSubstitute` and run into this problem. After all, now I can change normal chars but no (’) :(

Comment: @pmks It would be better to state clearly your problem about header manipulation.

Comment: well, then I better to open a new question. So I will.:)

Comment: As a matter of fact I opend a question about this header business recently [http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51574/hyperlinked-sectionnames-in-fancyheader] but that is a little bit obsolate now and well, nobody seems to be interested. What am I supposed to do? Open a new question or edit the old one?

Comment: @pmks Maybe editing the old one is the better option.