# LaTeX macro for Wikipedia article link

Tags: xstring

I'd like to create a LaTeX macro that will auto-create a link to a Wikipedia page for me.

```
 \usepackage{xstring}
 \usepackage{hyperref}

 % replaces the whitespace with '%20'
 \newcommand{\urlwhitespacereplace}[1]{\StrSubstitute{#1}{ }{\%20}}

 % takes an article name, replaces the whitespace, and concatenates to form the full URL 
 \newcommand{\wikipedialink}[1]{http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/\urlwhitespacereplace{#1}}

 % takes an article name and gives me a link called 'Wikipedia'
 \newcommand{\anonymouswikipedialink}[1]{\href{\wikipedialink{#1}}{Wikipedia}}
```

Then I try calling it like this...

```
 \urlwhitespacereplace{Charlie Bucket} %expected 'Charlie%20Bucket'

 \wikipedialink{Charlie Bucket} %expected 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charlie%20Bucket'

 \namedwikipedialink{Charlie Bucket} %expected 'Wikipedia' (hyperlink)
```

The first two work, returning exactly what you'd expect. However, when I use the third, I get...

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\Hy@href {->\hyper@normalise 
                         \href@ {
l.11 \namedwikipedialink{Charlie Bucket}
```

Could this have something to do with the the escaped % moving between the macros? Thanks for reading.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You didn't provide your code for `\namedwikipedialink`, please try to provide it in a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) (starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`) so we reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code.

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Nested macros and hyperlink problem](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51504)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Notes:

- Wikipedia escapes spaces with an underscore (`_`)
- Links *with* space do work, too.
- [Nested macros and hyperlink problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51504), [Martin Scharrer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51774/16595):

  > The correct syntax is `\hyperlink{<name>}{<text>}` where `<name>` must be a valid, expandable label name. It can not contain any non-expandable commands. […] The name must instead expand directly to some text only.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{hyperref}

%\newcommand{\urlwhitespacereplace}[1]{\StrSubstitute{#1}{ }{\%20}[\wpLink]}
\newcommand{\urlwhitespacereplace}[1]{\StrSubstitute{#1}{ }{_}[\wpLink]}
\newcommand{\wikipedialink}[1]{http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/#1}% needs \wpLink now
\newcommand{\anonymouswikipedialink}[1]{\urlwhitespacereplace{#1}\href{\wikipedialink{\wpLink}}{Wikipedia}}
\newcommand{\namedwikipedialink}[1]{\urlwhitespacereplace{#1}\href{\wikipedialink{\wpLink}}{#1}}

\begin{document}
\urlwhitespacereplace{Charlie Bucket} \par % no output
\wikipedialink{Charlie Bucket} \par % no substituting
\namedwikipedialink{Charlie Bucket} \par
\anonymouswikipedialink{Charlie Bucket}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh, just a redirect page … :-)

Answer (score 4):

My `texlinks.sty` in the [`morehype`](http://ctan.org/pkg/morehype) bundle provides macros for links to Wikipedia articles, see Section 8 
of `texlinks.pdf`, e.g., just `\Wikiref{`⟨lemma⟩`}` for the ["current" language.](http://ctan.org/pkg/langcode) The documentation proceeds from backbones to smarter macros, which may be difficult to understand quickly, sorry.

```
\documentclass{minimal} 
\usepackage{hyperref,texlinks} 
\begin{document} 
    Look up \wikiref{Charlie Bucket}{Wikipedia}
        for \Wikiref{Charlie Bucket}. 
\end{document}
```

That's "fwiw", haven't studied details of the question. 
The `texlinks.sty` macros work without [`xstring`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xstring), even with blanks 
in lemmas, I do not know exactly why, just seeing this here. 
Only referring to sections of Wikipedia articles needs "escaping" 
of blanks, umlauts, commas, ... I guess it's the [Wikimedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikimedia) ([MediaWiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MediaWiki)) engine 
that converts spaces into underscores etc.

Comment: Thanks to @percusse for help with editing and suggesting that I provide a MWE.

Comment: No problem. It's my pleasure.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) It’s great to have another TeXpert here.